# How to get "message" and "photo" from status message in group

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Among other API's (Twitter), I am using the Facebook Graph API to create a realtime "collage" of photo's and messages from Facebook, Twitter and a designated mailbox, so that all guests at a wedding can send in photos and messages, that will be projected using a beamer during the wedding.

I have successfully implemented retrieval of type="message" and type="photo" messages, but when it comes to fetching messages of type="status", the messages are missing the "message" property. Also, if a status was posted with a photo, I cannot find any way to retrieve the photo that was attached to the status message.

Is there any way (either via Graph or by using FQL), to get the "missing" information? The status messages in the group itself (viewing the group using Facebook) contain the text and the photo, so I believe the information should be available somewhere.

The details of the message that I get, look as follows:
(I have changed or deleted some of the properties for privacy reasons).
As you can see, there is no [message] property containing the text of the status update, nor is there any reference to the photo that accompanies this status update.

```
Array (
[id] => xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
[from] => Array
    (
        [name] => <name>
        [id] => xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    )

[to] => Array
    (
        [data] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [version] => 1
                        [name] => <name>
                        [id] => xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
                    )

            )

    )

[actions] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [name] => Comment
                [link] => http://www.facebook.com/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/posts/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [name] => Like
                [link] => http://www.facebook.com/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/posts/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
            )

    )

[type] => status
[application] => Array
    (
        [name] => Facebook for iPhone
        [namespace] => fbtouch
        [id] => xxxxxxxxxx
    )

[created_time] => 2012-05-26T16:00:00+0000
[updated_time] => 2012-05-26T16:00:00+0000
[likes] => Array
    (
        [data] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [name] => <name>
                        [id] => xxxxxxxxxxxxxx
                    )

            )

        [count] => 1
    )

[comments] => Array
    (
        [count] => 0
    )

)
```

I hope there is a way to retrieve the properties I need; it would be a shame if all photos that are posted as "status" message, cannot be used for the wedding presentation.